# Error: putting S3 policy: MalformedPolicy: Invalid principal in policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I was trying to deploy an S3 bucket with the terraform Code below:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "bucket" {
    bucket = var.s3_bucket_name
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "bucket_policy" {
    bucket = aws_s3_bucket.bucket.id
    policy = <<POLICY
{
        "Version": "2012-10-17",
        "Statement": [
            {
                "Sid": "CrossAccountEC2Access",
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Principal": {
                    "Service": [
                        "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:account_id:instance/instance_id"
                    ]
                },   
                "Action": ["s3:GetObject", "s3:PutObject"],
                "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::${var.s3_bucket_name}/*"
            }  
        ]
}
POLICY
}
```

When I did terraform apply, it came back with this error

> module.backup-s3-bucket[0].aws_s3_bucket_policy.bucket_policy: Creating...
> module.backup-s3-bucket[0].aws_s3_bucket_policy.bucket_policy: Still creating... [10s elapsed]
> module.backup-s3-bucket[0].aws_s3_bucket_policy.bucket_policy: Still creating... [20s elapsed]
> module.backup-s3-bucket[0].aws_s3_bucket_policy.bucket_policy: Still creating... [30s elapsed]
> module.backup-s3-bucket[0].aws_s3_bucket_policy.bucket_policy: Still creating... [41s elapsed]
> module.backup-s3-bucket[0].aws_s3_bucket_policy.bucket_policy: Still creating... [51s elapsed]
> ╷
> │ Error: putting S3 policy: MalformedPolicy: Invalid principal in policy
> │       status code: 400, request id: WGXE66WB8MT8EASW, host id: wFSAqlvst1/KmB/n5UrC77jQCCN33bZ3yJ1kbWrN3LmRCzsZ938CdRl9kkXHho3JNX1PNmNKSH9J/9NnH0retWcRbI4Y0/Av6hSLJ8s3lGA=
> │
> │   with module.backup-s3-bucket[0].aws_s3_bucket_policy.bucket_policy,
> │   on ../modules/backup-s3-bucket/main.tf line 9, in resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "bucket_policy":
> │    9: resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "bucket_policy" {

What am I doing wrong on the principal line?

I expected that the bucket policy will be created to grant cross account access to a particular ec2 in the cross account, but it returned the error mentioned above.

Answer (score 2):

The service should be

```
ec2.amazonaws.com
```

not

```
arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:account_id:instance/instance_id
```

Please refer to AWS docs [AWS service principals](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_principal.html#principal-services)  explaining what service principals are.

Comment: Thanks. I thought as much, but I need to give cross account access. My EC2 is in a different account from my s3 bucket. In this case, do I make the principal the root account?